# createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord не работает на андроид 4.4

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Устанавливаю связь по bluetooth с elm327.

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
btDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
_socket.connect();
```

Этот код прекрасно работает и держит соединение на устройстве с андроид 4.2, а на 4.4  соединение не устанавливается. В сети есть решение с использованием след кода:

```
Method m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", int.class);
_socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(btDevice, 1);
```

Соединение устанавливается, но оно не устойчивое, может и через несколько секунд оборваться, а может и через несколько минут. (т.е. при записи в OutStream возникает ошибка broken pipe). Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: Приветствую брата по несчастью. На самом деле это зависит не столько от версии Андроид, сколько от специфики самого дивайса. В моем приложении используется 5 различных способов создания соединения, и каждый покрывает определенные устройства. Но все равно не все. HTC Legend похоже не покрывает. Прошу прощения, что не могу выложить код, т. к. он находится под жестким NDA.

Comment: К примеру на Nexus 4 не работает блютуз если включен wify :)

Comment: @anber, вы на 100% неправы. Все рабюотает.

Comment: @metalurgus Я бы с вами с радостью согласился, если бы не столкнулся с этим на практике на двух девайсах Nexus 4. См. http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/bluetooth-wifi-connected-t2206594 или https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41631, или просто загуглите на тему "nexus 4 wifi bluetooth issues"

Comment: @anber, неужели кто-то до сих пор использует нексус 4 с Android 4.2.x?

Comment: @metalurgus на 5 андроиде тот же баг

Comment: а есть еще варианты с кодом для подключения?